unable to add startup applications
I just got a new computer with Ubuntu+Gnome preinstalled, put Cinnamon on it. I have been a Mint+Cinnamon user for a couple of years, still consider myself a beginner. I figured, like M+C, it would be easy to add apps to start automatically at logon time, just a browser and Nautilus, I use them everyday. The Startup Apps app in Cinnamon has Add App and Add Custom both grayed out, disabled. The Gnome Startup app has no selection for adding at all. I found the directory where startup apps go, just not sure what to put there. Is this permissions? I am a member of the Adm group. Thank you. Kernel 6.8, Ubuntu 22.04, Cinnamon 5.2.7.

Did you try to go to the system settings? There in XUbuntu is a "Session & startup behavior" symbol and there I can add the automatic started programs.

I went to both the Gnome and Cinnamon System Settings. Cinnamon add options are grayed out. In Gnome, when I select add (an application), and browse, it only browses files in the last directory where I opened something. I don't see a list of applications anywhere. I found an Add to Startup Applications option in the system tray launcher I use. That works for now. Thank you.
